# Four men working at a steel company

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

> Four men were working at a steel company. One day, they had a strange discussion about something.
>   - "God sends it", said Tom.
>   - "You wake up that way", asserted Dave.
>   - "It comes from above", replied Neil.

**What did James say ?**

Hint

> They are four big men, all working for the company owner, Sir Theodore Herbert Rash

Comment: Based on the tags, this seems like it could be very broad

Comment: Once the connexion is established, I can assure you it is not. But maybe I misused the tags, just don't pay too much attention to it (I removed it, riddle should be enough).

Comment: James says "What on earth are you babbling about?" :-)

Comment: Silliness aside, does the fact that they're at a steel company have relevance?

Comment: @Phylyp Yes, it's a clue :)

Comment: I added a hint!

Comment: Is the [tag:wordplay] tag applicable here? For other solvers, I couldn't find anything when googling for what was mentioned in the hint (with or without the steel company addition).

Comment: @Lolgast No, there is no wordplay.

Comment: Been wracking my brains wondering how to make "thrash metal" fit in here - "T. H. Rash Metal"!

Comment: I feel like that is wordplay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

James said

> Now that we're that way

or

> Creeping it

---

Sir Theodore Herbert Rash, owner of a steel company,

> abbreviated T. H. Rash, refers to thrash metal.

Tom, Dave and Neil are

> Tom Araya of Slayer, Dave Mustaine of Megadeth and Neil Turbin of Anthrax.

James is

> James Hetfield of Metallica.

These four are

> well known as the [Big Four of Thrash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Four_of_Thrash) (the bands, not the singers).

Their sentences refer to

> Songs released by their bands: God Sends Death, You Wake Up Dead and Death Comes from Above respectively.

The common concept is

> Dead or death. There are two Metallica songs that apply: Creeping Death and Now that We're Dead.

Comment: If this answer is correct, which it very much seems like it, I believe the riddle would have been better off with the "knowledge" tag.

Comment: Nice, I thought of 'thrash metal' but didn't take it further :-)

Comment: @Phylyp Yeah, that last hint made it so much easier! How familiar are you with thrash metal? Something that really helped me was knowing that there is a group of four specific bands that are considered more important than the rest.

Comment: Good job! My personal favourite answer would have been "It's creeping" (since it's the most iconic), but as you said there are mutliple possible answers ("It's magnetic" would have worked too, although it refers to an album and not a song).

Comment: Well, I listen to the big 4 (well, not much Anthrax) but I would never have thought of the members first names, it's always Araya, Mustaine, etc. to me. Nice job joining the dots like this 